Is it true that the Rebbe said if a person is getting something that isn't openly revealed as good they shouldn't say what did I do to deserve this
BH
Hi, Is it true that the Rebbe said if a person is getting something that isn't openly revealed as good they shouldn't say what did I do to deserve this? If he did say this what is the source?

Is mysticism-kabbalah the correct tag?
